Can someone please help me make this metal material?



Hello, Is someone able to help me make this material please. I am modeling screws and I can't seem to achieve that material with its imperfections
Thanks

Your references show at least 2 very different metals? And which imperfections you introduce for realism will depend on RL scale, casting, usage, etc. So it would be better to confine yourself to a single material reference if you can find it, and show us the objects you are actually making, as work in progress. IMO, this will probably attract more specific and relevant answers.

As @RobinBetts says, that's at least two different materials. The first image looks like a pickled steel surface slightly corrosive maybe or something similar but really hard to tell from that pic, while the other images are clearly zinc-galvanized surfaces much smoother apart from scratches and a little wear... but since you want to model screws I guess you're preferring the zinc-galvanized surface? But the small screws at the bottom could be made of stainless steel...

I got something like this, maybe it's fitting for your need:

If yes, here's the node tree:

Since it's procedural, you're able to change everything to your needs. Just play with the values a bit.
Note: this Setup works Cycles only since it's using the Bevel Node wich only works there. If you want your texture to be used in Eevee anyways, set it up in Cyles and bake the texture.
I hope it helps

Thank you very much. I do realise i had two materials in mind. The bottom was the one I was after. Thanks for you help.
